# How to build static library that I can use later on while compiling code with emcc?

Tags: c, static-libraries, emscripten

I'm building a third-party C library with emcc (version 1.38.38) in two steps:

1. Building static library (using emar) with *.a extension
2. Building a separate file with that static library.

Unfortunately I'm getting undefined symbols.
What I've tried so far:

- To build without emcc, using clang or gcc - everything working as expected
- To check whether symbols are in the library built (they are)

It looks like I'm missing something very elementary which I yet failing to find an answer about, so I'm asking you:

How to build static library that I can use later on while compiling code with emcc?

Comment: You mean "emcc" as in Emscripten? That's a compiler that produces JavaScript. How could it possibly create a native static library?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Well, I'm talking about this approach - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vvanders/wasm_lua/master/makefile
see, how lua-5.3.4/src/liblua.a is used  - this code was a source of inspiration for me but unlike mine this one is working

Comment: That code doesn't produce a library; it produces "main.js" that *uses* liblua.a, which is pre-made (presumably with gcc or clang, and presumably uses some API for communicating between native code and JavaScript/WASM).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker liblua.a is build  with emcc as well - you can try if you don't trust  me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, OK, I was stupid enough to ask this question, let me contribute to the community and confess what was the problem, may be it will help for someone else.

This code works:

```
 emcc -s WASM=1 -Isrc  main.c src/lib.a
```

while this won't

```
 emcc -s WASM=1 -Isrc src/lib.a main.c
```

The order is imporant so shame on me.

Comment: Interesting. Are these .a files some kind of WASM thing and not native libraries?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker my understanding is that it's a llvm bytecode.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I may have to play with that--I looked at Emscripten long ago but didn't have a use for it at the time. Looks like it's grown up a bit.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker it actually did! This is exactly what I'm doing right now - playing and having quite some fun - I also recommend to try it with rust - it's also fun )